# How to plot facet grid(ggplot in R) in python

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2

I looking to plot the following graph using python(matplotlib).

[image]

I am able to do this in R by the following code,

```
ggplot(delay.with.weather,
aes(x=pressure, y=dep.delay), na.rm = TRUE) + geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) +
facet_grid(season ~ ., scales="free") + stat_smooth(method=lm, na.rm = TRUE)
```

My trying is as follows,

```
plt.scatter(flights_combined.pressure,flights_combined.dep_delay)
plt.show()
```

I am not able to group by seasons column. Also not able to draw the regression line. Can anybody help me in doing these?

Comment: What about [python-ggplot](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/)?

Comment: I am running through anaconda ipython. Not able to install packages.

Comment: Do you use Pandas Dataframes?

Comment: @kazemakase yeah I use those

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/index.html) on top of matplotlib for such visualization, because it work very well with Dataframes.

The grouped scatterplots you can achieve by something like this:

```
grid = seaborn.FacetGrid(flights_combined, row='season')
grid.map(plt.scatter, 'pressure', 'delay')
```

See the documentation of [`FacetGrid`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) for more details.

If you want regression lines you can either do them manually (create your own implementation of plt.scatter that fits and draws regression lines on the data), or you may be able to find a way to use [`lmplot`](https://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) ([Example](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/multiple_regression.html)) in combination with [`FacetGrid`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html).